# Setting the corners of surface mesh parameterization with CGAL

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal, parameterization

I am playing with the square_border_parameterizer.cpp example from CGAL-4.14. I would like to not only choose the four corners but also to decide which is which. That is, I would like to specify, which corner will be assigned the parameter pair (0,0), which will become (0,1), which will become (1,0) and which will become (1,1). Is it possible?

I tried the Nefertiti example delivered with CGAL with several permutations of the selected corners.

corners1.selection.txt:

```
133 8 0 287
```

corners2.selection.txt:

```
8 0 287 133
```

corners 3.selection.txt:

```
287 0 8 133
```

However, result.off seems quite the same in all three cases when open in Meshlab.

I also had a look at the source code but I couldn't conclude yet how to achieve my goal. And as far as I can tell, the documentation only mentions that one can choose the four corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should tweak is the boundary halfedge taken in argument by the parameterizer.

Internally (in particular, in the function [compute_offsets()](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/934544dbdefbd17270f27e06f17463907bae8b34/Surface_mesh_parameterization/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh_parameterization/Square_border_parameterizer_3.h#L197) of `Square_border_parameterizer`), the corners are attributed their geometric uv position by walking the border, starting from the halfedge `bhd` that you have passed in input: the first corner met will be at `uv(0,0)`, etc.

Thus, if you want to modify which vertex is at `(0,0)` and looking at the [squared_border_example.cpp](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/934544dbdefbd17270f27e06f17463907bae8b34/Surface_mesh_parameterization/examples/Surface_mesh_parameterization/square_border_parameterizer.cpp#L130) that you were playing with, you can simply add:

```
  while(source(bhd, sm) != vda[i])
    bhd = next(bhd, sm); // walk the border
```

before the call to `SMP::paramterize()` with `i=0,...,3`, and you will obtain any rotation of the parameterized space you might want.

Comment: I followed your advice. From a few experiments it seems that `vda[0]` is then assigned the parameter value (0,0). However, the parameter values of the remaining points seem independent of their order; I suppose that they are determined from the orientation of the half-edges around `vda[0]`. Which is sufficient for my application. (-;

Comment: Since the input is supposed to be a topological disk, the vertices in the UV domain and on the input must appear in the same order, so, as you say, the other positions will be determined by walking the border.